# Is there a performance penalty for annotating a class with @XmlRootElement?

Tags: java, serialization, jaxb, marshalling

There is a class that is annotated with JAXB's `@XmlRootElement`, but there are some flows which doesn't exploit this annotation and which require high performance. Is there a performance penalty in constructing objects from this class and setting fields as opposed to doing so with the same class without this annotation?

Comment: Compared with the rest of the JAXB stuff involved, I'd be extremely surprised.

Comment: You are right. I edited the question and elaborated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There would be a small amount of memory used to store metadata related to a class being annotated with `@XmlRootElement`.  The only runtime processing impact related to the presence of that annotation would be when bootstrapping the `JAXBContext`.  There would be no impact on marshalling and unmarshalling.

Comment: "There would runtime processing impact related to..." -- what is the runtime processing impact?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, no, an annotation is metadata attached to the `Class` object, not to instances of the class.

The annotation will in no way affect creating instances and invoking methods on them directly.